# Remove <script> tag from dom using script id Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, for-loop

I am new to js and angular, appreciate your help here
I have a scenario where 3 scripts are added in the child compinent dom in ngOninit lifecycle id received from parent input.
Using `document.body.appendChild`  I want to remove all the script from dom on ngDestroy

```
<parent>
[id]="uniqueIds"
</parent>
<child>
@Input() id;
ngonInit(){
 var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");     
    scriptTag.id = this.id;
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
}
ngDestroy(){

  var domScriptsId = document.getElementById(this.id);
    if(domScriptsId != null){
      domScripts.forEach(function(s:any) {
        s.remove();
     });
    }
}
</child>
```

I tried using the for loop

but it throws error Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
Is there any other way I could achive this

Comment: All the scripts have the same id?

Comment: No the id is unique for each script

Comment: Can you include more of what your component does? Would be easier to help if we knew how your component adds the script. Maybe you could just store the element that is created locally and use that as reference to remove them on destroy.

Comment: component is just adding the script using document.body.appendChild for each id

Comment: So could you still provide more of the component? So we would know where or how you store the ids, or the element. So far all we see is some broken code. Please provide more so we can help you. Just edit your initial question and add the component code.

Comment: For example, where does `domScripts` come from, can't see where that is defined? If it's a typo and you meant `domScriptsId`, `domScriptsId` can't be an array, as `document.getElementById` only ever returns ONE element, not an array.

Comment: The parameter this.id (which is passed to document.getElementById) is the actual ids received from parent and in child those are used to create the script in dom

Comment: Welp, Inputs would be useful to know, as well as their types. Your question would have probably been answered already if you just provided more information about the rest of your component, like I asked you several times already....

Comment: type of Id is string

Comment: So how can it have multiple scripts if there's only one id being used? Again, `document.getElementById` only ever returns ONE element, never multiple, as ids on elements should always be unique. Maybe you are adding multiple scripts in your init, impossible to know. But I'm not going to drill further. As it stands right now, your question can not be answered without more details. If you want proper help, edit your question, add more details.

Comment: I have updated the comments hope I am much clear now

Comment: Still not clear how it is creating multiple Scripts like you stated before. I assume that `uniqueIds` contains multiple IDs, but you are only creating one script element in your init method. So there's no possible way as far as I can see that there should be more than one script existing. Also, there's a bunch of typos in there, please just provide your component AS IS, remove what you don't want to show, but provide a reproducable example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of ids, you can iterate over them, get each element with `document.getElementById`, then call [`Element#remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove).

```
idsToRemove.forEach(id => document.getElementById(id).remove());
```

Comment: The id are not stored in the array

Comment: @Yami Then how do you know which ids they are?

Comment: The id is passed from the parent component to the child and for each id using document.body.appendchild to add it in the dom

Comment: @Yami So each component only has one script to manage? If so, then just use `document.getElementById(this.id).remove()`.

Comment: no the child component has 3 scripts to manage since parent is sending 3 different ids

Comment: Then how is it receiving the ids if not in an array? @Yami

Comment: I have updated the question hope its clear now